# How to create a column that shows the number of times a value in another column appears without combining rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that looks like this:

```
+----------------+
| Account Number | 
+----------------+
| A0001          |
| A0001          |
| A0001          |
| A0002          |
| A0003          |
| A0003          |
+----------------+
```

I need to create a column that has the number of times an Account Number appears without changing the number of rows.

I know that

```
SELECT Account Number, COUNT(*) AS Counts
FROM database
GROUP BY Account Number
```

returns

```
+----------------+--------+
| Account Number | Counts |
+----------------+--------+
| A0001          | 3      |
| A0002          | 1      |
| A0003          | 2      |
+----------------+--------+
```

But I need something that looks like this:

```
+----------------+--------+
| Account Number | Counts |
+----------------+--------+
| A0001          | 3      |
| A0001          | 3      |
| A0001          | 3      |
| A0002          | 1      |
| A0003          | 2      |
| A0003          | 2      |
+----------------+--------+
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: `count(*) over (partition by "Account Number")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use count as a `window function` here:

```
Select AccountNumber, 
 count(*) over (partition by AccountNumber) as counts
from Table
```

Comment: That did the trick. Many thanks!